# Unix socket loops

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to implement a pair server/client programs that is able to exchange information through Unix Sockets. Problem is the client is constantly being reset and re-run by the server in a loop, and I'm having trouble sending/receiving data to and from the socket after the first time. Right now I have something like this:

#### Server:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    unix_socket server;
    server.initSocket(DEFAULT_SOCKET_PATH,SERVER_MODE);
    server.wait();

    bool first=true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {

            //send & receive data

        server.closeSocket();
        first=false;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Client:

```
int loop_controller(){
  unix_socket client;
  client.initSocket(DEFAULT_SOCKET_PATH,CLIENT_MODE);

  // receive & send data

  client.closeSocket();
}


int main () {

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i){
    loop_controller();
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

The **initSocket()**, **wait()** and **closeSocket()** members of `unix_socket` class (mode 0 for servers, mode 1 for clients):

```
void unix_socket::initSocket(const char* sock_path, const int sc_mode){

    if (sc_mode==0){
        if (mode != sc_mode) mode=sc_mode;
        if ((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            //exit(1);
        }
        // ---

        local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(local.sun_path, sock_path);
        unlink(local.sun_path);
        len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
        if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
            close(sock);
            perror("bind"); 
                    //exit(1);
        }
        // ---

    } else if(sc_mode==1) {
        if (mode != sc_mode) mode=sc_mode;

        if ((client_sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            //exit(1);
        }
        // ---
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(remote.sun_path, sock_path);
        len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
        if (connect(client_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
            perror("connect");
            //exit(1);
        }
        // ---
    } else printf("Invalid sc_mode argument: %d\n",sc_mode);
}
//...

void unix_socket::wait(){
    if (mode==0){
        if (listen(sock, 5) == -1) {
            perror("listen");
            //exit(1);
        }
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((client_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            //exit(1);
        }
    } else printf("Invalid call to wait(): mode %d\n, must be 0",mode);
}
//...

void unix_socket::closeSocket(){
    //close(sock);
    close(client_sock); 
}
//...
```

When running both programs with Valgrind, however, I'm getting SIGPIPE errors:

```
==5384== 
==5384== Process terminating with default action of signal 13 (SIGPIPE)
==5384==    at 0x573DDA2: send (send.c:28)
==5384==    by 0x405910: unix_socket::sendMsg(char, double) (in  .../server)
==5384==    by 0x405B6C: unix_socket::sendVectorXd(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (in .../server)
==5384==    by 0x402044: main (in .../server)
==5384==
```

I'm guessing that something is not being done correctly when closing/reopening socket. What would be the right procedure?

Comment: On the server side where is this reopening you speak of?  All I see is a close on the first pass of the loop.

Comment: You'll be getting a `SIGPIPE` if you try to write to an already closed (and blocking?) socket. Most applications would do well to ignore such signals using `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` [ though don't do this from your library ]

Comment: Additionally, your `perror()` calls should be done *immediately after* the failed operation. When you do `close(sock)` the `errno` is set by `close()` to indicate its success or failure, and thus you get the `errno` set by `close()` rather than `bind()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you are only `accept()`ing once. The end of the loop body indicates the client socket being closed, but yet it is never `accept()`ed again for the next iteration.

Your loop should be something like:

```
server.startListening(); // bind, listen and friends

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    server.acceptClient(); // Call accept
    // insert byte pushing routines here..
    server.closeSocket(); // call close() on socket returned by accept()
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I also need to `listen` again every time a client calls `close()`? And do I need to close also the server socket (on the server side)

Comment: I'm getting random (not able to replicate) `SIGPIPE` errors when closing the socket at the end of each loop, but everything works fine if I don't close the socket or just ignore `SIGPIPE` errors, do you know why that is?

Comment: No, you only need to listen once. `listen()` tells the kernel to open an accept queue for the current socket. `accept()` will basically pop the next item off that queue

Comment: As an application, you should handle `SIGPIPE`. You may also wish to check the return value of `accept` and such. You are probably still trying to do I/O on a close socket, or worse, closing a different FD